# "failed to open stream: operation failed" when using FTP URL wrapper with file_get_contents

Tags: php, ftp

I want to echo a XML file from a FTP server. I have the following code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('ftp://'. urlencode('*myusername*') . ':'. urlencode('*mypassword*') . '@www.ms5awhosting.de/20180306_0000035.xml');

echo $contents;
```

But I get the following warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(ftp://...@www.ms5awhosting.de/20180306_0000035.xml): failed to open stream: operation failed in ...

Has anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe there's more info in the part of the error that you did not provide? Have you tried searching for that error? What did that search turn up?

Comment: [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) needs to be enabled for this to work. Be careful turning this option on.

Comment: is there another option than allow_url_fopen? And I found nothing yet from searching this error

Comment: Can you download that file using any standalone (even GUI) FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code?

Comment: @pritaeas If `allow_url_fopen` was not enabled, OP would be getting a different error.

Comment: I can download it via FileZilla and I even changed the permission to 777 for the xml file

Comment: Do you run FileZilla on the same machine as your PHP code? Are you sure you use the same credentials in FileZilla as in your PHP code? I get the very same error message with your code, if I run it with random credentials, what hints that you use wrong credentials too.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry there was a 'm' missing in the credentials in my code, thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

One common reason that causes *"failed to open stream: operation failed"*, are  wrong FTP credentials specified in the URL.